# Get DialogFragment from FragmentManager by findFragmentByTag

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, dialog

I have create a progress dialog by DialogFragment, to do this I have use this article as base for my DialogFragment: https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/6421407 in fact on my application I have an activity that call a class and this class use AsyncTask to copy save some data inside a sqlite database.
I use progress dialog to show AsyncTask progress.

My code works, however a have a small problem: when the user rotate the device the progress bar is not update anymore because findFragmentByTag return always null.

This is a small piece of my code. I think the problem is here:

```
public class TafData {

private Context mContext;

public TafDownload(Context context) {

    mContext = context;
}

... other code ...

private class importTAFAsync extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, String> {
    ... other code ...
}

private void showProgress() {
    TafActivity tafactivity = (TafActivity) mContext;
    FragmentManager fm = tafactivity.getFragmentManager();
    ProgressDialogFragment pDialog = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance("Caricamento TAF", "Caricamento in corso. Attendere...", 100);
    pDialog.show(fm, "fragment_progress");
}

private void setMax(Integer... values) {
    ProgressDialogFragment progress = getProgressDialogFragment();
    if (progress == null) {
        return;
    }
    progress.setMax(values[0]);
}

private void updateProgress(Integer... values) {
    ProgressDialogFragment progress = getProgressDialogFragment();
    if (progress == null) {
        return;
    }
    progress.updateProgress(values[0]);
}

private void hideProgress() {
    ProgressDialogFragment progress = getProgressDialogFragment();
    if (progress == null) {
        return;
    }
    progress.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}

private ProgressDialogFragment getProgressDialogFragment() {
    TafActivity tafactivity = (TafActivity) mContext;

    Fragment fragment = tafactivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_progress");
    return (ProgressDialogFragment) fragment;
}
}
```

This is a piece of manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myapp.TafActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_taf">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="myapp.MapsActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?  Or at least your Activity declaration for TafActivity in your manifest.

Comment: @JDJ you need of all manifest or are looking for something in particular. I would like to avoid publishing all manifest if possible but if you think this can help I can do it.

Comment: I just need to see your <activity> declaration for TafActivity from the manifest.

Comment: @JDJ I have add a part of manifest on question.

Comment: Thanks.  Try adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to the activity declaration

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your  declaration for TafActivity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

This will prevent the system from destroying your activity on an orientation change.

Comment: Yes I know but I want allow user to rotate the device. I don't want block it.

Comment: This will still allow the user to rotate the device.

Comment: I have try to add your string on manifest. The screen can rotate but I have the same problem. After rotation the progress is not update because findFragmentByTag return null.

Comment: Before you call findFragmentByTag, try doing: `FragmentManager fm = tafactivity.getFragmentManager();`  `fm.executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: Did you get a chance to try it yet?

Comment: Sorry but I went to sleep after your comment :) I have try to add your code on showProgress() but I have the same result. If I add it on getProgressDialogFragment() I get an error: "Must be called from main thread of process"